# Compare two lists imported from a CSV and display only those that are the same

Tags: c#, list, csv

So, I'm using

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\....\Prices - Sheet1.csv"))
{
    using(var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
         productChange = csv.GetRecords<ProductChange>().ToList();
    }
```

to get the CSV files, and store them in their own list. One file will be altered daily (this one above) and the other is pretty static. Each CSV file has a description, barcode, and price. I'm trying to match the barcodes in the updated daily file and see if it's in our other file, if it is then I want to display that row saying it's a match. I've tried merging the lists and even using `for-each` to see if the barcode specifically matches but still nothing. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add minimal input data (two files of 5-7 lines should do), and desired output (see: [mre])

Comment: You have it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0

Comment: I've tried intersect too.  the thing is, in the first csv file it is up to 10 columns, in the other it is only 2, (the description and the barcode), I just need to check against the barcodes that have changed, and if they match in the second file then put them into a datagrid. I just can't seem to figure out how to use the contain function on two lists to see if they match.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell without a specific input/output code example, but it sounds to me that you may want to use [`.IntersectBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-intersectby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-1)))). You could play around with [this example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFA1JN) to see if it does what you need.

Comment: *Each csv file has a description, barcode and price* vs *in the other it is only 2*. Please make agreement